# How to reach Olympic Island before April?

Tags: public-transport, toronto

The [most iconic view of Toronto](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1843&bih=1317&ei=6QWTWon0Ho65ggf-9p_ABQ&q=toronto&oq=toronto&gs_l=img.3..0l10.944.2291.0.2632.8.6.0.2.2.0.114.344.4j1.5.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.7.357.0...0.QQIiKdRczG4#imgrc=yNrji2eIRucLPM:) seems to be taken from Olympic Island right across downtown. On Google Maps, it says there is a ferry from the Jack Layton Ferry Terminal that takes 32 minutes:

[image]

That would be great except that according to the [Toronto site](https://www.toronto.ca/explore-enjoy/parks-gardens-beaches/toronto-island-park/), it does not operate until April. However, the ferry to Ward Island operates but that look rather far from Olympic island to walk in  the cold.

**Is there public transportation that go fairly close to Olympic island in winter? Are there even taxis on these islands?**

Google Maps is of no help for this either. It says to Take the ferry to Toronto from Ward Island and then take the ferry to Olympic island:

[image]

Comment: Google Maps will behave better if you select walking directions, not driving directions — the Toronto Islands are car-free.  (It still tells you to take a ferry that's not currently running, though.)  You can also get walking directions from the Ward's Island Ferry terminal to Olympic Island, which Google Maps pegs at about 3 km or about 35 minutes.

Comment: What time of the year do you mean by Winter?  The high today in Toronto was 52° F which is hardly uncomfortable to be out and about in.  And of course the Scandanavian saying: "There is no such thing as bad weather, only bad clothes"

Comment: February in the evening, so temperature would be not so close to the high for the day and it gets cold very fast as soon as the sun goes down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ferries to the Toronto Islands run year-round.  You'll just have to take a ferry to Ward Island and travel from there.  It's a bit of a walk so I recommend to bring a bike.  Shouldn't be a problem if you're physically fit and properly dressed for the weather.  There's no taxi on the island, which is free from most motorised traffic.

Comment: Do they rent bikes in the area then at this time of the year? If yes, where?

Comment: @Itai I recall bike rental on the island is closed in winter, so you'd need to bring your own.  Various bike shops in town will probably rent you a bike any time of year as they're staffed anyway.  You can also bring one of those bikeshare bikes.

Answer (score 0):

**Since some links could be removed, I've simply typed the websites out for future research.**

The *torontoisland.com/ferry.php* site has information regarding the seasonal schedules:

> Winter service is to Ward's Island only starting 6:35am until 11pm. Check the ferry schedule online as boats do not run frequently during the winter.

[Toronto.ca](https://www.toronto.ca/explore-enjoy/parks-gardens-beaches/toronto-island-park/all-ferry-schedules/) will have more details regarding which ferry points are open. Winter season ends on April 8, 2018. You can even buy your tickets online there.

[Harbourfront Centre](http://www.harbourfrontcentre.com/marine/watertaxis/index.cfm) has info on water taxis:

- *TorontoHarbourWaterTaxi.com*
- *TikiTaxi.ca*
- *WaterTaxiNow.com*

*TorontoBicycleTours.com* will rent for various hours of the day or overnight, even up to 1 week.